# Grand Total sum for dynamic table using Formula property of Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm doing dynamic table (creating rows and column).

I know where it's start and end, as below on screen:
[image]

first row = a

last row = b

first col = c

last col = d

How to apply to **Grand total sum** into last row using vba using function like

`ws.Cells(x,y).Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,....)"`

?

Comment: Use pivot table.

Comment: I need to use vba, I can do other for loop, but function will be working faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
ws.Cells(b,c).Resize(, d - c + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTAL(9,R" & a + 1 & "C:R[-1]C)"
```